# difference between Master Public/private Key and Public/private Key?

Tags: private-key, public-key, bip32-hd-wallets

1. what is difference between Master Public Key (MPK) and Public Key?
2. what is difference between Master Private Key and Private Key?
3. should I use master public key (MPK) when generating address or public key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With **"Master public key"** you probably refer to deterministic key derivation after bip32.

The correct term is **"Master extended private key"** (acronym **xpriv**) and **"Master extended public key"** (acronym **xpub**).

The acronyms are "xpriv" and "xpub" because the base58 check prefix results in those 4 characters for a mainnet extended pub/priv key.

The difference between a **extended** public key and a normal public key is that it also contains information about the bip32 chain (deterministic chain/hierarchy).

It contains:

- The *depth* in the hierarchy (1byte 0x00 for master nodes, 0x01 for level-1 derived keys, ....)
- A fingerprint (4 bytes, possible identifier)
- The *chaincode* (32 bytes, = link used for the hierarchy)
- The *child index* ("number" of the key at the current hierarchy level)
- The *private or public key* (32bytes for private-, 33bytes for public-key)

A normal private- or public-key only contains the last element (32/33byte [public|private]key).

**A (simplified) example how you would generate addresses:**

1. Take the extended master private key (`m/`)
2. Derive an account extended private key (`m/0'`)
3. Take this account extended private key (`m/0'`) and derive the first extended private key on the next level (`m/0'/0`).
4. Use the extended private key of (`m/0'/0`) to generate the extended public key and take out the "normal public key" (33 bytes) and encode a P2PKH address (or P2WPKH, multisig, etc.) out of it.